# Get hours from schedule

Tags: google-sheets-formula

How can I get the total working hours scheduled with this format?
Expected output should be 46.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest things, but here are two ways to tackle it

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SUM(
   IFERROR(
    INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(A2:G2)," - ",FALSE,TRUE),0,2)-
    INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(A2:G2)," - ",FALSE,TRUE),0,1)))*
  24)
```

or

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SUM(
   IFERROR(
    REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")-
    REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)")))*
   24)
```

Either way, we extract the second values then subtract the first values from that, sum it, and multiply it by 24.

For overnight shifts, try this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SUM(
   IFERROR(
    IF(
     --REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")<(--REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)")),
      1+REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")-
      REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)"),
      REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")-
      REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)")))*
   24))
```

in `[hh]:mm:ss`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  TEXT(
   SUM(
    IFERROR(
     IF(
      --REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")<(--REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)")),
       1+REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")-
       REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)"),
       REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")-
       REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)")))),
   "[hh]:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: That's awesome! How can I adapt it for a schedule 23:00 - 8:00? I get -75 instead of 45 since is 9 hours times 5 days

Comment: ok @mau, check the post for the last formula, which should handle overnight shifts.

Comment: The last formula actually works for both! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hello! Can you adapt to have in hh:mm:ss format please?

Comment: no prob, @mau -- all we need to do is ditch the `*24` and wrap that part in TEXT. Check the post for the full formula.