# Change format to hh:mm:sss

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, extract

Can I adapt this formula to make the result into `hh:mm:ss` format instead of just a raw number?

[Get hours from schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72521408/get-hours-from-schedule/72522591?noredirect=1#comment128114625_72522591)

```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(
      SUM(
       IFERROR(
        IF(
         --REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")<(--REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)")),
          1+REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")-
          REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)"),
          REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")-
          REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)")))*
       24))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(IF(
 --REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")<(
 --REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)")),
 1+REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")-
   REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)"),
   REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"- (\d+:\d+)")-
   REGEXEXTRACT(A2:G2,"^(\d+:\d+)")))*24), "[hh]:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: I get 00:00:00 instead of the actual number

Comment: @mau can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I cant since I have sensitive information but I posted a ss of the example

Comment: @mau hard to tell for sure... try `hh:mm:ss` instead of `[hh]:mm:ss`

Comment: I've got the same result

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion

Based on your question & on your previous post, you want to sum up the time from range `A2:G2` ***OR*** `AR2:AX2` (as seen on your sample screenshot) in `hh:mm:ss` format. Perhaps you can try this tweaked function below:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(TRANSPOSE(
{
ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(AR2:AX2,"- (\d+:\d+)"),0)),
ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(AR2:AX2,"^(\d+:\d+)"),0))
}
)))), "[hh]:mm:ss"))
```

> This function was derived from an answer on this quite [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60440245):

### Demonstration

[image]